# Can I use Wake-on-LAN to turn my computer off?

Tags: shutdown, wake-on-lan

I use the following command to turn on another computer (running Windows):

```
wakeonlan 74:d0:2b:92:0f:fa
```

However, I would also like to be able to *turn off* the computer. How can I do that?

Comment: WOL - as it name says - is only for waking up a device (if prerequisites are met) - to turn off a computer running windows you could send a remote shutdown command

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: you could use [psShutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) - this of course assumes you have network accessibility (accessible IP or FQDN) and credentials for the computer to shut down.